# Assign group permissions on folders using Powershell via CSV

Tags: permissions, powershell, scripting, access-control-list, csv

we are working on a new Permission Concept.
We created different Security Groups,depending on the Department.

For example:

```
Finance_List, Finance_Read, Finance_ReadWrite
Controlling_List, Controlling_Read, Controlling_ReadWrite
Planning_List, Planning_Read, Planning_ReadWrite
```

Now I am searching for a script to automate the process for setting GroupPermissions on specific Folders.

Example:
**Folder Finance**:
*Disable Inheritance* and then set new permissions and replace them to all files and subfolders: 
*Group Finance_List* (List Folder), *Group Finance_Read* (Read), Group *Finance_ReadWrite* (Modify)

CSV Example (Folderpath and the 3 GroupPermissions per Folder):

```
\\cifs\Finance;Finance_List;Finance_Read;Finance_ReadWrite
```

I have 300 securitygroups and 100 folders.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you what you need (make sure that the groups in your CSV match the name of the group in AD or it won't work correctly):

```
$Folders = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Folders.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Header "Path","List","Read","ReadWrite"

ForEach ($F in $Folders) {
    $ACL = Get-Acl $F.Path

    # Set the first parameter to $true to disable inheritance
    # Set the second parameter to $false if you don't want to retain a copy the permissions to this folder.
    # Set the second parameter to $true if you want to retain a copy of the inherited permissions.
    $ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)

    # 'ReadData' grants List Folder / Read Data
    $List = New-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($F.List,"ReadData","Allow")
    $ACL.SetAccessRule($List)

    # 'ReadAndExecute' grants Traverse Folder / Execute File
    # 'Read' only grants List Folder / Read Data
    $Read = New-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($F.List,"ReadAndExecute","Allow")
    $ACL.SetAccessRule($Read)

    $ReadWrite = New-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($F.ReadWrite,"Modify","Allow")
    $ACL.SetAccessRule($ReadWrite)

    $ACL | Set-Acl $F.Path
}
```

This website has good examples of how to modify this if needed as well as a list of the various Access Rights and their Powershell equivalent.
[How to Manage File System ACLs with PowerShell Scripts](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/)